# AWS Cognito API Authentication flow SDKs

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, boto, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to figure out what is the authentication flow with AWS Cognito (from a golang client for instance, or python with Boto). Basically registered user gets a token from Cognito and uses it to log in to the app server.

[image: Simple Auth Flow with Cognito]

What I figured out so far:

1. User sign in with SignUp()
2. User Code Verification with ConfirmSignUp()
3. How does the user get its token?
4. How does the user provide it's token to a 3rd party server?
5. How does the 3rd party server verify the user token ?

The official documentation is talking about Authentication Challenge but I do not see it in the Golang or Python API libraries.
How can I validate steps 3, 4 and 5 please ?

Thank you very much in advance

API Doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed here:docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/… page 70.

There is not an actual implementation example but this is way good enough to understand the process.

Comment: Pointing to the actual section would be better rather than mentioning a page number which could change with the addition of content.